# Solving equation with fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I don't understand how to get from the second to the third step in this equation:

$  - \frac { \sqrt { 2 - x ^ { 2 } } - x \left( \frac { - x } { \sqrt { 2 - x ^ { 2 } } } \right) } { \left( \sqrt { 2 - x ^ { 2 } } \right) ^ { 2 } } = - \frac { \sqrt { 2 - x ^ { 2 } } + \frac { x ^ { 2 } } { \sqrt { 2 - x ^ { 2 } } } } { \left( \sqrt { 2 - x ^ { 2 } } \right) ^ { 2 } } = - \frac { \frac { 2 - x ^ { 2 } } { \sqrt { 2 - x ^ { 2 } } } + \frac { x ^ { 2 } } { \sqrt { 2 - x ^ { 2 } } } } { \left( \sqrt { 2 - x ^ { 2 } } \right) ^ { 2 } } = - \frac { 2 } { \left( \sqrt { 2 - x ^ { 2 } } \right) ^ { 3 } } $

Why can we just add $ 2 - x ^ { 2 } $ in the numerator?
Step 1 to step 2, as well as step 3 to step 4 is clear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You multiply by $1$ in a fancy fashion:

$$\sqrt{2-x^2}=\sqrt{2-x^2}\cdot 1=\sqrt{2-x^2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}=\frac{(\sqrt{2-x^2})^2}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}=\frac{2-x^2}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}$$

This of course only holds if $2-x^2\neq 0$, as otherwise also $\sqrt{2-x^2}=0$ and the last expression(and the intermediate ones) would be ill-defined.

---

Note, that his holds for any $a\in (0,\infty)$ by the same method as above, i.e.

$$\sqrt{a}=\sqrt{a}\cdot 1=\sqrt{a}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}=\frac{(\sqrt{a})^2}{\sqrt{a}}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a}}$$

Comment: In the top: The last is not equivalent to the first if $x = \sqrt 2$.  Same error as above.

Comment: @amWhy same comment as above

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : Note that $2-x^2 = (\sqrt{2-x^2}) * (\sqrt{2-x^2})$ and $(\sqrt{2-x^2}) = \frac{2-x^2}{(\sqrt{2-x^2})}$

Comment: The last equation holds provided $x \neq \sqrt 2$.

Comment: Indeed, the whole problem isn't defined on that point anyway. @amWhy

Comment: @amWhy This goes for all answers, nevertheless as OP uses loads of fractions with $\sqrt{2-x^2}$ in the numerator, I guess we all assumed the condition to be given.

Comment: It *is* given.  But it should be pointed out.  If $\frac M{\sqrt M}$ equals anything (assuming real numbers) then $\frac M{\sqrt M} = \sqrt M$.  But that doesn't mean $\frac M{\sqrt M}$ does actually equal anything.

Comment: The initial problem was to calculate the first and second derivative of $ f ( x ) = \sqrt { 2 - x ^ { 2 } } $ in the interval of $ ( - \sqrt { 2 } , \sqrt { 2 } ) $

So x could be $ \sqrt { 2 } $ by definition of the problem...

Comment: @Viviana How were we supposed to know? It's written nowhere in your question as of today.

Comment: You couldn't. That's why I wrote it to you now as a reply to your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Is because for any $y>0$
$$
\sqrt{y}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{y}}. 
$$

Comment: It should be ....$y>0$,  ):

Comment: dmtri this can be said of all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply that for $a>0$, $$\sqrt{a} = \sqrt{a}\cdot\underbrace{\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}\right)}_1$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}$$
$$=\frac{(\sqrt{a})^2}{\sqrt{a}}$$
$$=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a}}$$
In your case, "$a$" is $2-x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Because for $a > 0$ we know $\sqrt a = \frac a{\sqrt a}$ so $\sqrt{2 -x^2} = \frac {2-x^2}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}$ (assuming that $2 - x^2 > 0$ which must be the case as you have had $\sqrt{2 - x^2}$ in the denominator elsewhere in the equation).

Comment: As P. before you, and others before you, watch out if $\sqrt a = 0$

Comment: Good point.  As $\sqrt {2 - x^2}$ is in a denominator that is the case here.  But in general you are right.